# Overcome Excel Size Limit to Analyse a Large Network Useage

Tags: oracle, excel, matlab, octave

I am analysing CPU useage on a large network. In order to do that, I was provided with a large excel sheet. It contains batchID (means we dedicate a CPU to run that task) startTime, endTime (means we know the CPU is fully occupied during this time).

Based on this data, I need to understand how many batches are running at a particular instance. Therefore, I will use a chat with x-axis been the time and y-axis been the count of batches running at each time instance.

The whole file is over 15000 rows over two days's data. Here is a fraction of it.

```
BATCHID     startTime             endTime
560062  13/10/2011 11:59:23 13/10/2011 11:59:26
560061  13/10/2011 08:59:18 13/10/2011 08:59:21
560060  13/10/2011 05:59:21 13/10/2011 05:59:30
560059  13/10/2011 02:59:34 13/10/2011 02:59:43
560058  13/10/2011 01:57:24 13/10/2011 01:57:29
560057  13/10/2011 01:57:24 13/10/2011 01:57:28
560056  12/10/2011 23:59:19 12/10/2011 23:59:28
560055  12/10/2011 20:59:21 12/10/2011 20:59:30
560054  12/10/2011 18:02:13 12/10/2011 18:02:22
560053  12/10/2011 18:02:13 12/10/2011 18:02:21
560052  12/10/2011 18:02:12 12/10/2011 18:02:21
560051  12/10/2011 18:02:07 12/10/2011 18:02:16
560050  12/10/2011 18:02:03 12/10/2011 18:02:11
560049  12/10/2011 18:02:10 12/10/2011 18:02:19
560048  12/10/2011 18:02:11 12/10/2011 18:02:16
560047  12/10/2011 18:02:09 12/10/2011 18:02:13
560046  12/10/2011 18:02:04 12/10/2011 18:02:13
560045  12/10/2011 18:02:12 12/10/2011 18:02:21
```

Requirment:

1. We need array to contain the time slice data. This could be every 1 minuts or 5 minuts. If we need to analyse two days for every 1 minuts interval, we could then need 2880 data points for the x-axis.
2. Because at any instance there are could be many jobs running. We'll need to device a mechnism to count number of running batches at that time slice.

I suspect Excel 2003 can do a good job as the number of columns is limited to 256.

I'm welcoming any advise on how to permoer this task efficiently in Octave/MATLAB, ORACLE PL/SQL, R or Bash Script.

Overcome Excel Size Limit to Analyse a Large Network Useage

Answer (score 0):

I would change the data to be something like:

```
BATCHID START/END  TIME                NUM_TASKS
560062  START      13/10/2011 11:59:23    1
560062  STOP       13/10/2011 11:59:26    0
```

Order it by TIME and compute NUM_TASKS as the previous line's value +1 for a START and -1 for a STOP. Then you can just plot TIME vs NUM_TASKS and do whatever smoothing or intervals you want in the graph itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate how will you arrive +1 and -1?

Comment: If a task STARTS then the total number of running tasks goes up by one. If a task STOPS then the total number of running tasks goes down by one.